# How can we identify files/folders with unique permissions in G-Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to identify all files/folders in Google Drive, either My Drive or Shared/Team drives, that have unique permissions? For example:

- Someone selected a file/folder and got a shareable link
- Folks have been explicitly given access?

I was checking the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) documentation but `getEditors` and `getViewers` also shows inherited access.

Comment: Check drive api too

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You can try using the Drive API:

```
function getperms(){ 

  var files = Drive.Files.list({supportsAllDrives:'true', q:'trashed = false'}).items;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    var perms = Drive.Permissions.list(files[i].id).items;
    Logger.log("=========FILE=========");   
    Logger.log("File id: " + files[i].id + " File name: " + files[i].title);

    Logger.log("=========Permissions=========");
      for (var x = 0; x < perms.length; x++){ 

        Logger.log("Role: " + perms[x].role + " Email: " + perms[x].emailAddress);

      }
    }

  }
```

It might be interesting to put an `if` condition to avoid your own email, as it returns all the permissions from all the files, including yours. You can also search for specific emails.

Also, take a look at the [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) and [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource-representations) Resources Representations to see all the items from each one.